# bootstrap modal pop not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code. I don't know why the modal pop up not popping up when clicking on the login button. I checked and confirmed that `data-target` and `data-toggle` are set correctly. Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Ritesh Sangwan">
    <title>ossoc | Create account</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqwidgets/jqxvalidator.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!------ Navabar start --->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

            </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.jsp">ossoc</a>
            </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-btn">
                        <button id="loginbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#registerlogin" data-toggle="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>Login</button>
                    </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!---- navbar end--->

        <div class="container marketing">
            <div class="jumbotron-modified well">
                <div class="container">
                    <form id="register" action="register" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input id="fnameInput" name="registerfname" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input name="registerlname" type="text" class="form-control" id="lnameInput" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input name="registeremail" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="someone@example.com" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input name="registerpassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirmInput" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                <div id="acceptInput">
                                  <input type="checkbox" />  
                                  I accept the terms and conditions.  
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Create account</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  



            <footer>
              <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
              <p>&copy; 2013 Ritesh Sangwan. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
     <!--- Model start-->  

      <div class="modal fade" id="registerlogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                 <h3>Login</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="login" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Log in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!---model end ---->


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including jQuery before Bootstrap.  Your bootstrap.min.js is before your jquery.

[Bootstrap Modal doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463344/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-show)

Comment: including jquery before bootstrap solves the problem but I don't understand why is it so. After all both the scripts will load the the page load. So how it matters the sequence. Can you explain.

Comment: The first script is bootstrap, on loading, it's looking for jQuery for the features that require it (Modal being one of those).  If jQuery isn't there WHEN bootstrap loads, it won't backtrack and go looking for it after the fact, it simply breaks.  Looking through some of the docs, actually, and it seems a little unclear.  Bootstrap should probably be a little more adamant about including jquery FIRST, as it's a common problem.