# bootstrap modal not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My modal div is:

```
<div class="modal" id="showmodal"><!-- content here --> </div>
```

Now I am calling it with **data-toggle='modal'** following anchor is coming with DOM:

```
<a class="c" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmodal">click </a>
```

and its working.
Now when I appending another link from javascript like following

```
<a class data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmodal">click </a>
```

It's not working. Can anybody tell why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463344/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-show/20463582#20463582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have added first a tag

```
<a class="c" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmodal">click </a>
```

bootstrap.js knows on which element it need to attach model window event.
but when you dynamically appended

```
<a class data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmodal">click </a>
```

bootstrap.js does not know the element exists in DOM.
so you need to manually call the js function to open model.

```
$('#showmodal').modal(options)
```

In your JS code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i think they used a delegate event !

Comment: It is not mentioned in there doc.