# Show a modal form onchange of a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a ASP .NET MVC application in which users should be able to add content to a page. This content can be things like a location, photos, ...
I have a dropdownlist in my View with all the different content options. When an option is selected, the page should show a modal form where they can enter details based on the type of content they selected.

My modalform is constructed like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="locationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Map</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                <form id="locationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add location</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's easy to fire up the modal with a button with the data-toggle and data-target attributes like this:

```
<p class="text-center">
    <button id="addLocation" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#locationModal"></button>
</p>
```

But how do I achieve this form to be shown when selecting a value from the dropdown list? I have added a JS function to the OnChange of my dropdownlist select but I don't know how to fire up the modal form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the modal using javascript on the change event of the dropdown.

Just check this link :

[Bootstrap Modal doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463344/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-show/20463582#20463582)

Comment: Thank you! That link helped me out.